# Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a) - when I try to subscribe to a BLE characteristic on Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense

Tags: node.js, arduino, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using [Noble.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abandonware/noble#event-services-discovered) to connect my [Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano-33-ble-sense). Everything works fine rather than subscribing. When I try to subscribe via `characteristic.subscribe([callback(error)]);`, I see the following on `sudo btmon`, the related part is as follows:

```
ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                     
  ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
    Read By Type Request (0x08)
    Handle: 0x0013
    Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
```

If we check the flag from [here](https://software-dl.ti.com/simplelink/esd/simplelink_cc13x2_sdk/1.60.00.29_new/exports/docs/ble5stack/vendor_specific_guide/BLE_Vendor_Specific_HCI_Guide/att_api.html?highlight=0x0a), it says the same thing. I am able to subscribe via [generic BLE app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en_GB&gl=US) without any issues. So, how can I debug this further?

BlueZ version is 5.50.

The full `btmon` log:

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 18                                                                                      #101 [hci0] 216.091528
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Scan response - SCAN_RSP (0x04)
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: 09:16:8C:47:5F:71 (OUI 09-16-8C)
        Data length: 6
        Name (complete): Nano
        RSSI: -73 dBm (0xb7)
    < HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                            #166 [hci0] 20.855945
        Scanning: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                       #167 [hci0] 20.856820
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25                         #168 [hci0] 20.861549
        Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Scan window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
        Filter policy: White list is not used (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: 09:16:8C:47:5F:71 (OUI 09-16-8C)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Min connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)
        Max connection interval: 15.00 msec (0x000c)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 2000 msec (0x00c8)
        Min connection length: 2.500 msec (0x0004)
        Max connection length: 3.750 msec (0x0006)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                         #169 [hci0] 20.862080
      LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                                         #170 [hci0] 21.168187
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Role: Master (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: 09:16:8C:47:5F:71 (OUI 09-16-8C)
        Connection interval: 15.00 msec (0x000c)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 2000 msec (0x00c8)
        Master clock accuracy: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 13                               {0x0002} [hci0] 21.168288
        LE Address: 09:16:8C:47:5F:71 (OUI 09-16-8C)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 0
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 13                               {0x0001} [hci0] 21.168288
        LE Address: 09:16:8C:47:5F:71 (OUI 09-16-8C)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 0
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                  #171 [hci0] 21.168529
        Handle: 64
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                         #172 [hci0] 21.169549
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 14                                      #173 [hci0] 21.169670
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                    ..........      
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                         #174 [hci0] 21.187752
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Features: 0x2f 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Connection Parameter Request Procedure
          Extended Reject Indication
          Slave-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                        #175 [hci0] 21.196651
      ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
        Client RX MTU: 256
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                        #176 [hci0] 21.232587
      ATT: Exchange MTU Response (0x03) len 2
        Server RX MTU: 247
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 11                                       #177 [hci0] 21.236291
      ATT: Read By Group Type Request (0x10) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0001-0xffff
        Attribute group type: Primary Service (0x2800)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                            #178 [hci0] 21.262750
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 24                                       #179 [hci0] 21.278151
      ATT: Read By Group Type Response (0x11) len 19
        Attribute data length: 6
        Attribute group list: 3 entries
        Handle range: 0x0001-0x0005
        UUID: Generic Access Profile (0x1800)
        Handle range: 0x0006-0x0009
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (0x1801)
        Handle range: 0x000a-0x0013
        UUID: Environmental Sensing (0x181a)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 11                                       #180 [hci0] 21.280267
      ATT: Read By Group Type Request (0x10) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0014-0xffff
        Attribute group type: Primary Service (0x2800)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                        #181 [hci0] 21.307537
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Group Type Request (0x10)
        Handle: 0x0014
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 11                                       #182 [hci0] 21.310329
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0001-0x0005
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                            #183 [hci0] 21.322723
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 20                                       #184 [hci0] 21.337681
      ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 15
        Attribute data length: 7
        Attribute data list: 2 entries
        Handle: 0x0002
        Value: 020300002a
        Handle: 0x0004
        Value: 020500012a
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 11                                       #185 [hci0] 21.340017
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0006-0x0009
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 13                                       #186 [hci0] 21.367572
      ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 8
        Attribute data length: 7
        Attribute data list: 1 entry
        Handle: 0x0007
        Value: 200800052a
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 11                                       #187 [hci0] 21.368173
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x000a-0x0013
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                            #188 [hci0] 21.382744
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 27                                       #189 [hci0] 21.398165
      ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 22
        Attribute data length: 7
        Attribute data list: 3 entries
        Handle: 0x000b
        Value: 120c006e2a
        Handle: 0x000e
        Value: 120f006f2a
        Handle: 0x0011
        Value: 1212006d2a
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 11                                       #190 [hci0] 21.398694
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0009-0x0009
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                        #191 [hci0] 21.427558
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Type Request (0x08)
        Handle: 0x0009
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 11                                       #192 [hci0] 21.428283
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0013-0x0013
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                            #193 [hci0] 21.442725
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                        #194 [hci0] 21.472559
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Type Request (0x08)
        Handle: 0x0013
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 11                                       #195 [hci0] 21.474417
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x000b-0x000d
        Attribute type: Client Characteristic Configuration (0x2902)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                        #196 [hci0] 21.502541
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Type Request (0x08)
        Handle: 0x000b
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                            #197 [hci0] 21.661765
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 1
```

I am using [ArduinoBLE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ArduinoBLEBLECharacteristicBLECharacteristic) lib. on the Arduino side. The notification feature is added via:

```
BLEShortCharacteristic temperatureCharacteristic( BLE_UUID_TEMPERATURE, BLERead | BLENotify );
```

Comment: Maybe you could post the full btmon log? Does the characteristic include "notification" as a feature in the characteristic properties definition?

Comment: @Emil I have added the full log. Yes it does, I can see that in the Node-RED output as well. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to subscribe via app, isn't it?

Comment: Well something seems to be wrong with your GATT server since it says that the Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor cannot be found, even though the Notify bit is set in the characteristic properties. A Bluetooth stack can possibly use other GATT procedures to subscribe, but clear is that something is wrong on your server side which should be fixed nevertheless.

Comment: It seems like, I need to add [descriptor](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ArduinoBLEBLECharacteristicaddDescriptor)? Maybe app can does not require and can automatically handle. I will update after adding one.

Comment: Technically a Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor is not needed at the server, at least with Android, to receive notifications. But if you want to follow the standard, you must have one that works as specified.

Comment: @Emil, the problem was with the client not with the server. I was not able to set notification bit to 1. After I set, it works as expected.